# raise ValueError No gradients provided for any variables -Custom loss function

Tags: keras, deep-learning, neural-network, loss-function

I'm writing a custom loss function for a neural network with keras back-end, to reduce attitude error.

```
def LossQuat(y_true, y_pred):
        a, b = y_true.get_shape()
        error  = np.zeros([a,1])
        for i in range(a):
            w0,x0,y0,z0 = y_true[i,:]
            w1,x1,y1,z1 = y_pred[i,:]/tf.norm(y_pred, ord='euclidean', axis=None, keepdims=None, name=None)
            w = w0 * w1 - x0 * x1 - y0 * y1 - z0 * z1
            error[i,] = tf.square(2*tf.math.acos(w))
        err = tf.reduce_sum(error)
        return tf.reduce_mean(err)
```

The model is:

```
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(100, input_dim=1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense((4), activation='linear'))

model.compile(loss=LossQuat, optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-5),run_eagerly=True)

# training
batch_size = 32
epochs = 1000
model.fit(x_train, quat_pitch, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, verbose=1)
```

But I got this error:

> raise ValueError(f"No gradients provided for any variable:
> {variable}. "

> ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable:
> (['dense/kernel:0', 'dense/bias:0', 'dense_1/kernel:0',
> 'dense_1/bias:0'],). Provided `grads_and_vars` is ((None, <tf.Variable
> 'dense/kernel:0' shape=(1, 10) dtype=float32, numpy= array([[ 0.027,
> 0.718,  0.436,  0.588,  0.597, -0.712,  0.038,  0.629,
> 0.305,  0.463]], dtype=float32)>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense/bias:0' shape=(10,) dtype=float32, numpy=array([0., 0., 0., 0.,
> 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_1/kernel:0' shape=(10, 4) dtype=float32, numpy= array([[ 0.449,
> 0.503, -0.456,  0.521],
> [-0.365,  0.423,  0.55 ,  0.032],
> [-0.311,  0.348, -0.056,  0.174],
> [ 0.521,  0.498, -0.131, -0.507],
> [-0.107,  0.321,  0.638,  0.117],
> [ 0.248,  0.416, -0.259, -0.273],
> [ 0.121,  0.137, -0.575,  0.094],
> [ 0.41 , -0.565, -0.394, -0.239],
> [-0.531, -0.056,  0.13 ,  0.201],
> [ 0.225, -0.122,  0.556, -0.266]], dtype=float32)>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_1/bias:0' shape=(4,) dtype=float32,
> numpy=array([0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)>)).

What is my mistake?

I tried to use Keras Loss Functions such as MSE. When I used them the model has been trained without any problem.

Also, for the custom loss, I tried different batch size, for all of them the problem is exist.

**DATA SHAPE**

```
x_train.shape = (304414,)
y_train.shape = (304414,4)
```

**MATH:**

The main formula is as follows:

```
quat_predict * inverse(quat_ref) = [w ,x, y, z]
```

The error:

```
error = 2*arccos(w)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tensorflow [cannot track gradients through object assignments](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6193) like your code with errors. This creates a copy of a value, and thus the gradient is not defined. Instead you should put things into a list, or vectorise the whole thing.

```
def LossQuat(y_true, y_pred):
        a, b = y_true.get_shape()
        error = []
        for i in range(a):
            w0,x0,y0,z0 = y_true[i,:]
            w1,x1,y1,z1 = y_pred[i,:]/tf.norm(y_pred, ord='euclidean', axis=None, keepdims=None, name=None)
            w = w0 * w1 - x0 * x1 - y0 * y1 - z0 * z1
            error.append(tf.square(2*tf.math.acos(w)))
        err = tf.reduce_sum(error)
        return tf.reduce_mean(err)
```

Note that now the list is composed of `tf.Tensor` object that has a functional dependency on your predictions. Before the output would be a numpy float, with a dependency lost.